# Circle division

Tags: riddle, geometry

There are three of me in every perfect circle. Yet when divided into four identical arcs my number shrinks to two.

What am I?

Hint:

> *Originally asked as*:
>  There are three of me in every **perfect circle**. Yet when divided into **four identical arcs** my number shrinks to two.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are

> the letter C.

Explanation:

> in every "perfect circle", the letters C and E (and no others) each appear exactly three times. E appears once in "four identical arcs", but C appears twice. So the answer must be C.

Comment: That was quick. Too easy? Thoughts on how to perhaps disguise the answer better?

Comment: @Zymurge The trouble with puzzles like this is that once you've seen one, every new one of the same type is easy. Any puzzler who already has this idea in their repertoire will look for a single-letter answer as soon as they see something like "there are $n$ of me in X", and it will only take seconds to identify the right solution.

Comment: Some people are just really good at riddles. This riddle is by no means easy at all.

Comment: If I un-bolded the keywords, would that help hide the answer. My thinking was that if I didn't call out the specific words somehow, it'd be too arbitrary.

Comment: @greenturtle3141 I won't deny that [some people are really good at riddles](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help/badges/131/riddle) ( :-) ), but it's just luck that I happened to see this one so quickly - there are dozens of other people here who I'm sure would have got it just as quickly.

Comment: @Zymurge The new version is definitely slightly harder - still wouldn't take long to solve IMO, but it's not so immediately obvious.

Comment: @zymurge I have to agree with rand here. As soon as I saw "# in word" I just counted letters and there was "C"....then I scrolled down and it was already answered. So not a bad puzzle - just a well known format that is easily solved by those who know the format.